# What does Harm. mean in guitar tabs

Tags: guitar, notation, tablature, harmonics

In the *Nothing Else Matters* tab by Metallica on [songsterr.com](https://www.songsterr.com/a/wsa/metallica-nothing-else-matters-tab-s439171/r451407), I came across some notation that I haven't seen before:

[image: Guitar tab with "Harm. - - - |" above some notes.]

What does “Harm.” mean in the picture above?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Harm. Just means to play the harmonics at that fret. The diamond is also the same instruction of playing harmonics at the 12th fret.

The 12th fret has very strong harmonics that are the same note as the string played on, just at higher octaves.  Harmonics in general also have a very distinct tone from just playing the 12th fret.

The strength of the harmonic on the 12th fret is due to how the harmonic series works and the 12th fret aligning with the second harmonic node. I'd recommending looking into the harmonic series if you are interested in this concept as there's a lot going on there.